# Does a redefinition of the cluster level change estimation consistency?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, panel-data, least-squares, multilevel-analysis

I have a linear panel data model:
$$ y_{it} = \alpha + x_{it}\beta + e_{it} $$
for individuals $i$ and period $t$. Assume conditions for Pooled OLS consistency hold.

I also observe the region $r$ where the individual lives. Define as the new cluster the pair individual-region, $k(i,r)$, where the same individual living in different regions is treated as different units. The new model would be:
$$ y_{kt} = \alpha + x_{kt}\beta + e_{kt} $$
Is Pooled OLS still consistent?

Comment: So you're saying in the second case there would be more observations because you observe the same person in 2 different regions? If that's the case then it should be consistent because that individual x regional variation is already taken care of in your individual level weak exogeneity.

Comment: In the first case, the cluster is the person. In the second, is the person-region pair. Number of observations are the same.

Comment: In that case then weak exogeneity should hold because reordering the clustering doesn't affect $E(e|X)$ because the reordering could be thought of as a function and weak exogeneity holds for all functions of X. I've got Wooldridge's panel book around somewhere I'll look more into it.

Comment: I've got it too! But I cannot find anywhere a comment on this type of transformations.